# how to know public ip and port behind NAT

Tags: python, nat

I have a client behind NAT and a server who is accessible by this computer

something like this :

```
  local ip    external ip IPe
              external port Pe
C --------- | ----------------- S
           NAT
```

I want S to know C IPe and Pe used to transmit between those two

how can i do it ?

I'm using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If S is the server then just do**

```
 conn, addr = s.accept()
```

**Else if C doesn't know anything about S**
Here is a solution for you problem: You should use an intermediate server that will resolve the communication problem for you.

1. C connect to the server and send his external port number (the
   IPe is automatically known by the server).
2. The server store IPe and Pe.
3. S ask the server for C and gets the IPe and the Pe.
4. Then S can contact C by its own

*Requirement:*

- TCP connection
- S and C are client
- An intermediate server

*NOTE: the secret is that both C and S knows the server.*

Comment: It's exactly what i have. 
if I is my intermediate server
How does C send his external port number to I ?
After, how I can store the IPe ?

I is also in Python

Comment: On S, when C connects you should have: `conn, addr = s.accept()`.

So you have the `addr` which contains the ip and the port of C.